# Set radius just in large screens with tailwind css

Tags: css, responsive-design, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to make an image have border radius only when the screen is large, otherwise I want it to have straight edges, how can I do that?

I am using Nextjs and Tailwind CSS

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `lg:` or `xl:` prefix on whatever class you want to conditionally apply according to screen size, take a look at the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design)

Here's an example code:
`pages/index.js`

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="h-full w-full grid place-items-center">
      <div className="w-32 h-32 bg-red-500 lg:rounded-xl"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-dew-jqx1h?file=/pages/index.js)